i got an error in python anywhere for wrong password or username
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/PixelXl81/django_starter.git/'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Pixel/.local/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py", line 49, in <module>
    main(
  File "/home/Pixel/.local/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py", line 31, in main
    project.download_repo(repo_url, nuke=nuke),
  File "/home/Pixel/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pythonanywhere/django_project.py", line 20, in download_repo
    subprocess.check_call(['git', 'clone', repo, str(self.project_path)])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/PixelXl81/django_starter.git', '/home/Pixel/pixel.pythonanywher
e.com']' returned non-zero exit status 128.

i tried api token that i get from python anywhere too but again i getting this error

It's good that you posted the error, but that by itself is not enough to help us locate the problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The code is trying to access a private GitHub repo/non-existent repo, which needs a username and a password. And of what I can see of your error, you provided the wrong username and password.
